# Global extrema of $(x^2 + y^2)e^{-(x^2 + y^2)}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-verification

Could anyone please check my solution to the following problem?

> **Problem:** Let $f(x, y) = (x^2 + y^2)e^{-(x^2 + y^2)}$. Find global extrema of $f$ on $M = {\mathbf R}^2$.

**Proposed solution:** Taking partial derivatives of $f$, we conclude that critical points are $[0,0]$ and points of the unit circle $C = \{[x,y] \in {\mathbf R}^2:\ x^2 + y^2 = 1\big\}$.

We can reason immediately that the global minimum is attained at $[0,0]$ as the function is nonnegative. We observe that the value of $f$ on $C$ is $e^{-1}$.

To prove that $f$ attains global maximum on $C$, we let $r := x^2 + y^2$. We observe that for any two points $[x_1,y_1]$ and $[x_2,y_2]$, $r_1 = r_2$ (ie. the function is constant on circles). Now let $r \to \infty$. Then
$re^{-r} \to 0$. From the definition of limit, it follows that for any $\varepsilon > 0$, we find $\delta > 0$ such that

$$\forall r \in P(\infty, \delta) = ({1 \over \delta}, \infty): re^{-r} < \varepsilon.$$

Let $\varepsilon = (2e)^{-1}$. Then there's $\delta$ from the definition above and we know that for $r \in ({1 \over \delta}, \infty)$, the value of f is less than the value of f on $C$. Restricting ourselves to the compact set

$$C' = \big\{[x, y] \in {\mathbf R}^2:\ x^2 + y^2 \le {1 \over \delta}\big\},$$

we can now argue that $f$ on $C'$ is indeed maximized on $C$, as it is a continuous function on a compact set, it's value around the boundary is at most $(2e)^{-1}$ and all critical points have been considered.

Therefore, the maximum value of $f$ is attained on $C$ with respect to $M$ as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks good. Note that you can also start by translating the problem into a one-dimensional problem by letting $g(r) := re^{-r}$ and finding the global maximum and minimum of $g$ on $[0, \infty)$ and then note that $f(x,y) = g(x^2 + y^2)$ and conclude.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Is my approach a standard one, or is there some other approach that may be applied to such problems (proving local extrema points are global) in general, such as the one you propose?

Comment: Your approach is fine - I only suggest that you check ahead whether the function involved has any special symmetry that allows you to reduce the problem to a one-dimensional problem. It won't always be possible, and then you will have to use arguments similar to the one you gave (dividing $\mathbb{R}^n$ into a compact area and an unbounded area on which the function is bounded, etc). Your solutions exploits the symmetry anyway and in my opinion, it would have been easier if you would have done it in the beginning.

Comment: Great, thanks again! As I was looking for (a) confirmation of my argument and (b) a notion of general approach I should take when dealing with such problems, I am accepting your answer. Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 2):

$$e^x\ge1+x \quad \forall x\in\mathbb{R}$$

(this is well-known / can be established all sorts of ways. Note that equality holds $\iff x=0$)

Take $x=d-1$ to see

$$e^{d-1}\ge d\implies de^{-d}\le e^{-1}\implies(x^2+y^2)e^{-(x^2+y^2)}\le e^{-1}$$

Chase back the fact that the equality holds when $x=0\iff d=1 \iff x^2+y^2=1$ to see that this maximum is attained, and that it is attained only on the unit circle.

Minimum is trivial for the reasons you detail - the function is non-negative, and $0$ only at the origin, so the global minimum is $0$ and achieved at $(0,0)$.

Comment: Now this is clever! I always enjoy solutions that build the problem from known facts. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could just remark that the function is radial with value $f(x) = |x|^2 e^{-|x|^2}$. so if it has a maximum/minimum at $x_0$, it's on the whole circle of radius $|x_0|$.

So it suffice to study the function $h(t) = t^2 e^{-t^2}$.

Here you can just differentiate, $h'(t) = (2t - 2t^3) e^{-t^2}$, and this is equal to $0$ for $t=\pm 1$, and it's easy to check that it's a maximum.

Hence $f$ is maximal on all $x$ such that $|x| = 1$

Answer (score 1):

This looks correct to me, but one can treat this a little more efficiently: If $f$ achieves a global extremum at $(x, y)$, then the map $g: [0, \infty) \to \Bbb R$ defined by $$g(r) := r^2 e^{-r^2}$$ achieves a global extremum at $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ and vice versa. Since $g$ is differentiable, to determine the latter it's enough to find the value of $g$ at the solutions of $g'(x) = 0$ and the value $g(0)$ at the endpoint $x = 0$. As was observed in the question, we know that $g$ achieves a minimum at $x = 0$ because evaluating gives that $g(0) = 0$ and $g(r) \geq 0$ for all $r$ (as $g$ is a product of nonnegative functions), leaving us just to solve $g'(r) = 0$, evaluate $M_a := g(r_a)$ for each solution $r_a$, and determine the maximum of the values $M_a$.